# Discord Bot gamejolt integration?

Tags: bots, integration, discord

I have a question, I would like to do integration with gamejolt in my discord bot, it's about showing the number of views, downloads, likes of a particular game. Is there any integration with gamejolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GameJolt's API for that: https://gamejolt.com/game-api/doc